# Pass an integer to a timer in WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have my [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) built in timer:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timerLoop;
```

When the timer is started, I want (if possible) to pass this timer an integer value.

```
timerLoop.Start();
```

Till now, I only created a general variable that the timer can read and update this variable just before starting my timer.

Comment: When you say 'pass' you mean pass to the event handler of the timer event an integer variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this two ways (maybe more):

Extend base `Timer` by creating new one that inherit it:

```
private class TimerExnteded : Timer
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public TimerExnteded(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

and use that value in `Tick` event.

Use `Tag` property of `Timer`

```
Timer t = new Timer();
 t.Tag = 5;
 t.Start();

 //event
 private void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     var timer = sender as Timer;
     var value = (timer.Tag as int?) ?? 0; 

     value++;

     timer.Tag = value;
 }
```

Second approach uses boxing/unboxing of value.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use closure:

```
t.Tick += (s, a) => OnTick(YourValue);
```